# A blind person needs to move "Indoor or indoors" environment

Tags: adjectives

> A blind person needs to move "indoor" or "indoors" environment

Which one is correct in this?

"Indoors" is adverb so it doesn't modified the noun here "environment".

Comment: You're almost there. If it's not the adverb (*indoors*), then it must be the adjective (*indoor*). You'll need a preposition ("to" or "into") and an article ("an"). "A blind person needs to move **to an** indoor environment." Which isn't necessarily true.

Comment: A blind person needs to move **indoors** environment. So this sentence is wrong, I cannot use **indoors** . It should be indoor then add preposition and article like you said.